# How to diagnose bimodal connection speed between home PC and commercially hosted server

Tags: networking, home-networking

I have a problem between my home PC and my server at a hosting company (Hetzner).

Both machines have a 1 Gbit/s connection to the Internet.

I have done lot of iperf3 tests. Three out of 10 of my iperf3 runs report a decent speed (300 - 400 Mbit/s). The others only run at 1-3 Mbit/s

When iperf3 starts, if it starts at a decent speed, it will remain at a decent speed no matter how long the test lasts. But sometimes the second after the test ends, I will try again and then it starts at 1-3 Mbit/s and remains at the same speed.

I tried some traceroute tests to find the problem but there was nothing wrong.

What could cause the connection speed to be bimodal like that? Maybe a different route? What can I try to diagnose the problem?

Comment: " iPerf limits the bandwidth for UDP clients to 1 Mbit per second by default."  Or perhaps your ISP is limiting your bandwidth...

Comment: I've seen a problem like this happen at work when a switch with two redundant load-balanced 10G links to the router had a problem with one of the two links becoming flaky. It was hard to predict which link a given TCP connection would be load-balanced onto, but any connections that landed on the bad link would be very slow. Try doing a bunch of **single stream** speed tests from home to a third-party server, and from your hosted server to a third party server. See if you can isolate the problem to the hosting company or your home ISP.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do some tests with another hosting company